# find reviews has more than one tag. in many to many polymorphic laravel relation

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many

hi I'm trying to use many to many polymorphic but somehow it doesnt work
I couldn't get related reviews in many-to-many polymorphic relation
I want get a review by tags, selected by customer

Table Structure:

```
review
> id - integer
> name - string

tags
> id - integer
> name - string

taggables
> tag_id - integer
> taggable_id - integer
> taggable_type - string
```

Models:

```
class Tag extends Eloquent
{
    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Review::class, 'taggable');
    }

}

class Review extends Eloquent
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable');
    }
}
```

> > > the request from customer [tag_id_1,tag_id_2,tag_id_3,tag_id_4]

the request like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array of tags-key

if a review related to this tags find and get the review, i tried something like that

Code for return related reviews:

```
return Review::join('taggables', 'taggables.taggable_id', '=', 'reviews.id')
        ->where('taggables.taggable_type', '=', Review::class)
        ->whereIn('taggables.tag_id', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
        ->groupBy('reviews.id')
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

OR:

```
Review::WhereHas('tags', function ($query) {
        $query->whereIn('tags_id', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    })->get();
```

**the result i need:
The only reviews that should have these tags**

```
review:{
name: "Review",
tags :[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

> [laravel eloquent relationships many-to-many-polymorphic](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

Comment: I don't think this is enough information at least you need to show a code that sends the request or the data form after the request and also the structure of your table and how data are stored by showing just couple of rows.

Comment: `return $this->morphedByMany('Review', 'taggable');` I dont think a string that just says 'Review; would work there. It has to be `'App\Review'` assuming the model has the `App` namespace. Otherwise, import it and use Review::class. In the join, the problem is probably `Review::class`. Data will be stored as App\Review as type if I'm not mistaken (not sure about this, morphed models are not my thing).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.
More information added

Comment: @emadghaffari did you mean to say that your relationship already references the model by class name, instead of the string as shared at first?

Comment: @user3532758 Thank you very much for the explanation.Yes, it was a mistake in my writing that I did not explain in full here

Comment: see if changing id to tags_id works `$query->whereIn('tags_id', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);` In the mean time I'll have a look through the documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. 
Yes absolutely right.
I corrected the question.
But I just want to find just a review that has all the tags [1,2,3,4,5] and 
This method will find all the reviews that have these tags [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: No, adding tags_id won't work there.

Comment: @emadghaffari `$query->whereIn('hashtag_id', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);` why is there a hashtag_id? This is new information. it should have worked with the way it was before. And, do please take note of the typo mentioned in the answer, but it should have worked with the whereIn if your database table structure is as you shared.

Comment: @emadghaffari can you share a screenshot of your `taggables` table?

Comment: sorry hashtag is typo. It works well but
Reviews that even have the one tag are also received. I just need to get an review that has all these tags [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: Your question was a little confusing then. I've added an answer showing one way to hopefully achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the review that has all tags, this is one way to do it:

```
$tagIds = [1,2,3,4,5];
$reviews = Review::query();
foreach($tagIds as $id){
 $reviews->whereHas('tags', function($query) use ($id) {
   return $query->where('id', $id);
 });
}
$reviewsWithAllThoseIds = $reviews->get();
```

---

```
//if you don't want to use foreach.
collect($tagIds)->each(function($id) use ($reviews){
    $reviews->whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($id) {
        return $q->where('id', $id);
    });
});
```

This should give you the reviews that has all tags that has the ids in the array.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. but id not work and worked tag_id well $query->where('tag_id', $id);

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in your query.correct form of   `taggables.tagable_id` should be `taggables.taggable_id`. I don't know this is the problem or not but suggest to write your code like below.

in the review model define relations like this:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable','taggables','taggable_id','tag_id');
}
```

and in Tag model define relation like :

```
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Review::class, 'taggable','taggables','tag_id','taggable_id');
}
```

and when you want return reviews  of a specific tag do it like:

```
$tag=Tag::find(1);
$tagReviews=$tag->reviews;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.
I need to receive an review that has more than one tag.

Comment: in the  question, you said  " I want get a review by tags, selected by customer"